# How to split text inside button

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have problem with new line... I want Fontawesome icon be on top and text under that. Can someone explaing how to do it?

Here is my code:

```css
.options_button{
 float: left;
 width: 113px;
 height: 57px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
 border-top-right-radius: 0px;
 border-top-left-radius: 0px;
 padding: 5px;
 border: 2px solid;
 border-color: #5f6a77;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/css/all.css">
<button class="options_button">
  <i class="fas fa-image"></i>
  Save
</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done many ways such as:

- Make the icon a block element.
- Add a `<br>` tag.
- Make the text wrapped in a block element.

(*NOTE: There are many more ways, these are just a few*)

#### Display Block Icon:

```css
.options_button {
    float: left;
    width: 113px;
    height: 57px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-color: #5f6a77;
}

.options_button i {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/css/all.css">
<button class="options_button">
  <i class="fas fa-image"></i>
  Save
</button>
```

#### Break Tag:

```css
.options_button {
    float: left;
    width: 113px;
    height: 57px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-color: #5f6a77;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/css/all.css">
<button class="options_button">
  <i class="fas fa-image"></i><br />
  Save
</button>
```

#### Display Block Text

```css
.options_button {
    float: left;
    width: 113px;
    height: 57px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-color: #5f6a77;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/css/all.css">
<button class="options_button">
  <i class="fas fa-image"></i><br />
  <div>Save</div>
</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to use `flexbox`:

```css
.options_button{
 width: 113px;
 height: 57px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
 border-top-right-radius: 0px;
 border-top-left-radius: 0px;
 padding: 5px;
 border: 2px solid;
 border-color: #5f6a77;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/css/all.css">
<button class="options_button">
  <i class="fas fa-image"></i>
  Save
</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add a br to make a new line

```css
.options_button {
  float: left;
  width: 113px;
  height: 57px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-color: #5f6a77;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/css/all.css">
<button class="options_button">
  <i class="fas fa-image"></i>
  <br/>Save
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the "Save" text in a span then display the span tag "block" in your CSS. Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L8671utp/)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/css/all.css">
<button class="options_button">
  <i class="fas fa-image"></i>
  <span>Save</span>
</button>

button span{
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Why would you ever use `<span>` for a block element? There is `<div>` for that.

Comment: @MichałSadowski Because a div inside a button is considered invalid by W3C a span tag is not. That's why.

Answer (score 1):

Try it, is less code and clean.

```css
.options_button{
 width: 113px;
 height: 57px;
  border-radius: 0px
 padding: 5px;
 border: 2px solid #5f6a77;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/css/all.css">
<button class="options_button">
  <i class="fas fa-image"></i>
  Save
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **br** tag to force a linebreak.

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/css/all.css">
  <style type="text/css">
    .title {
      color: blue;
      text-decoration: bold;
      text-size: 1em;
    }
    .author {
      color: gray;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <button class="options_button">
    <i class="fas fa-image"></i>
    <br>
    Save
  </button>
</body>
</html>
```